# Selenium - Cannot locate elements in page source

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to crawl a web page using Selenium, but for some reason the elements I need are not showing up in the page source

I've tried using a WebDriverWait until the page loads. I've also tried to see if the data is in a different frame that I need to switch to.

```
driver.get('https://foreclosures.cabarruscounty.us/')

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="app"]/div[5]/div/div')))
    print("Page is ready!")

    web_url = driver.page_source
    print(web_url)

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

I would expect to see all of the records for each individual property card that I could then extract. However, the page source does not show any of this data.

If I manually load the web page and inspect the source, the data just does not exist view-source:https://foreclosures.cabarruscounty.us/

Comment: The obvious answer is the element indeed does not exist.  Are you absolutely sure the xpath is right?

Comment: Yes the xpath is correct.

Comment: What data are you looking for in this page

Comment: For each record I want the Real ID, Case Number and Owner field.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.It would return all the elements.Use `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://foreclosures.cabarruscounty.us/")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='app']//div[@class='card-body']/div[1]")))
allrecord=[ele.text for ele in elements]
print(allrecord) #it will give you all record.
```

If you just print 1st element value.

```
print(allrecord[0].splitlines())
```

You will get below output:

```
['Real ID: 04-086 -0040.00', 'Status: SALE SCHEDULED', 'Case Number: 18-CVD-2804', 'Tax Value: $29,660', 'Min Bid: $10,067', 'Sale Date: 10/03/2019', 'Sale Time: 12:00 PM', 'Owner: DOUGLAS JAMES W', 'Attorney: ZACCHAEUS LEGAL SVCS']
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first *Real ID*, *Case Number* and *Owner field* you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://foreclosures.cabarruscounty.us/");
  Real_ID = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='card cardClass']/img//following::div[@class='card-body']//div/b"))).text
  Case_Number = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='card cardClass']/img//following::div[@class='card-body']//div//following-sibling::b[2]"))).text
  Owner = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row']//div[@class='card cardClass']/img//following::div[@class='card-body']//div//following-sibling::b[7]"))).text
  print("{} is {} owned by {}".format(Real_ID,Case_Number,Owner))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Real ID: 04-086 -0040.00 is Case Number: 18-CVD-2804 owned by Owner: DOUGLAS JAMES W
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ImplicitWait and PageLoad for waiting for the elements:

```
//For 30 seconds
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
```

This code is for C# and Selenium

Comment: I am not sure the wait or page load is the issue. The data I need just straight up does not exist in the page source, even if I manually load the web page and inspect.

Comment: Ok, I tried to go to https://foreclosures.cabarruscounty.us/, but the site can’t be reached